# How can I determine why the error label is not destroying?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a tic-tac-toe game and the game worked but the error label is not destroying, I tried to use grid_forget but it didn't work. How can I debug this?

```
def send():
    global columns, rows, columnlabel, rowlabel, send_b, restart, rowlist, columnlist, reg, rb1, rb2, error1, error2, error3, error4
    global board, colsize, rowsize, errors

    errors = 0
    error = Label(reg).grid(row=5)

    while int(rows.get()) >= 6 or int(columns.get()) >= 12:
            if int(rows.get()) >= 6:
                errors +=1
                if errors >= 2:
                    error = Label(reg, text="ERROR THE AMOUNT OF ROWS IS TO BIG")
                    error.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
                    rows.delete(0, END)
                    rows.insert(0, "")
                    return
                else:
                    error = Label(reg, text="The Amount Of Rows Is To Big Please Try Again")
                    error.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
                    rows.delete(0, END)
                    rows.insert(0, "")
                    return
            elif int(columns.get()) >= 12:
                errors +=1
                if errors >= 2:
                    error = Label(reg, text="ERROR THE AMOUNT OF COLUMNS IS TO BIG")
                    error.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
                    columns.delete(0, END)
                    columns.insert(0, "")
                    return
                else:
                    error = Label(reg, text="The Amount Of Columns Is To Big Please Try Again")
                    error.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
                    columns.delete(0, END)
                    columns.insert(0, "")
                    return

    # Save The Column Size And The Row Size
    columnlist.append(columns.get())

    rowlist.append(rows.get())

    columnlist[0] = int(columnlist[0])
    rowlist[0] = int(rowlist[0])

    rowsize, colsize = rowlist[0], columnlist[0]

    board = [[0 for j in range(colsize)] for i in range(rowsize)]

    # Print The Board
    # Destroy All Of The Screen
    columns.destroy()
    rows.destroy()
    columnlabel.destroy()
    rowlabel.destroy()
    send_b.grid_forget()
    rb1.destroy()
    rb2.destroy()
    error.destroy()
    
    # Run Start Game And Start The Game
    startgame()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have too many duplicated `Label` widgets in `send()` function?

Put `Label` widgets outside of the functions or whatever you put.

```
error = Label(reg, text="ERROR THE AMOUNT OF ROWS IS TO BIG")
error.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Then use `error.configure` in send() function.

Code:

```
def send():
    ...

    while int(rows.get()) >= 6 or int(columns.get()) >= 12:
            if int(rows.get()) >= 6:
                errors +=1
                if errors >= 2:
                    error.configure(text="ERROR THE AMOUNT OF ROWS IS TO BIG")                    
                    rows.delete(0, END)
                    rows.insert(0, "")
                    return
                else:
                    error.configure(text="The Amount Of Rows Is To Big Please Try Again")
                    rows.delete(0, END)
                    rows.insert(0, "")
                    return
            elif int(columns.get()) >= 12:
                errors +=1
                if errors >= 2:
                    error.configuretext="ERROR THE AMOUNT OF COLUMNS IS TO BIG")
                    columns.delete(0, END)
                    columns.insert(0, "")
                    return
                else:
                    error.configuretext="The Amount Of Columns Is To Big Please Try Again")
                    columns.delete(0, END)
                    columns.insert(0, "")
                    return
```

PS: Let me if this could work.